# Adding data to the table with asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, database, dom

I have a html-css table. I want to add data to the table from ms access database with asp.net.

Anyone who teaches on the web uses gridview. But I want to use my own table. Literal is very useless and tiring.

Is there any other way I can add data inside the table from code behind. I guess I should use loops when adding data,

I have a lot and varying amount of data. That's why I can't use html DOM with C#. Or can i?

Comment: you can also use repeater

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that but you can do it very much easier using the gridview facilites.
Keep in mind that when you are using HTML DOM you are working with the client side and when you are working with C# it is the server side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I liken griedview to my own table using html and css? Sorry im beginner.

Comment: You can create a gridview with the same structure of your table and you can use styles and css just like that: https://parallelcodes.com/styling-the-gridview-in-asp-net/

Comment: Thank you so much. I am very happy about that. Good work:)